# What is oracle event record?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I got this question from an interview. Never heard before. I have searched the google but not much help. I ended up here

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17069/strms_change_table.htm#CHDJCEJB

but I didn’t understand a single thing. I need to know what is this event record in oracle, what is it do, how to create them or access them and what the purpose is or why we need it and where it is located.

If you have simple query or something please share me

I don’t know anything about it so please answer me in simple English

Comment: Never heard of it. Google says it may be related to Fusion Middleware (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/dev.1111/e14301/store.htm#CEPED218) (which I also know nothing about).

Comment: What was the actual interview question? Or do you just want general advice about Oracle Streams?

Comment: it was a telephonic interview ... first they asked what is event record? i said i don't know  second they asked do you know how to select event records from tables in oracle.  i also never heard this this ..may be  the person asked the wrong  question ...i don't know

Comment: I’ve never heard of it either as an Oracle feature. I don’t think there is one. Perhaps they were thinking of some application that logs events of some sort.

Comment: After reading a little about oracle streams, I think they were asking about streams which can record events happening to the table (like DML and DDL). Because a table can have only DDL and DML events right?